# Install Hadoop in openstack

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, openstack, hadoop2

I'm new to big data. And I have a question about the installation of hadoop.
Currently I use an image on VirtualBox, but I would like to create a cluster on the openstack. At first I thought I just need to instantiate a hadoop image on the openstack or install several instances and use the hadoop docker image.
But I found several examples of the Sahara openstack. Knowing that I already have an openstack shared with several people, is it possible to create a hadoop cluster without going through openstack Sahara? Or is it not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about "Sahara Openstack", but you can surely create Hadoop cluster using VM nodes on openstack.

Single node installation guide
http://tecadmin.net/setup-hadoop-2-4-single-node-cluster-on-linux/#

Comment: Thank you for your response, but in this guide I can only install a single node cluster. For our use case we need more than 15 VMs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to create Hadoop cluster on OpenStack cloud without using OpenStack sahara. You can launch 3 Virtual machines on OpenStack, and assign floating IP to these virtual machines.
One can be used as Master and other 2 as slaves. You can follow the Hadoop multinode installation steps on these virtual machines and connect them using SSH configuration which will be mentioned in Hadoop multinode setup guide.

You can also write automated shell script for launching Hadoop on OpenStack.

Comment: Thanks, please is it possible to connect an hadoop cluster set on physical to openstack without using virtual machines on openstack ?